# itext7.pdfHTML library how to fix it to support multiple languages

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I have a created sample project for try to test the itext7.pdfHTML library. I think this library supports the English language only, But I think it's impossible to remember only one language support. Please help me to fix it to support multiple language. **I will convert html to pdf only** and **I use itext7.pdfhtml 3.0.4**

Controller

```
public IActionResult TestPDFHtml()
        {
            string html = @"<html><head><meta http-equiv=""content-type"" content=""text/html""; charset=""UTF-8""></head><body>สวัสดี</body>";
            TestPDF test = new TestPDF();
            byte[] vs = test.creatPDFByte(html);
            return File(vs, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Code method creatPDFByte

```
public byte[] creatPDFByte(string pdfHTML)
        {
            byte[] buffer;
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (PdfWriter pw = new PdfWriter(ms))
                    {
                        pw.SetCloseStream(true);
                        using (PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pw))
                        {
                            ConverterProperties cProps = new ConverterProperties();
                            cProps.SetCharset("UTF-8");
                            pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                            pdfDoc.SetCloseWriter(true);
                            pdfDoc.SetCloseReader(true);
                            pdfDoc.SetFlushUnusedObjects(true);
                            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(pdfHTML, pdfDoc, cProps);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    buffer = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch ...
```

Comment: *"I think this library supports the English language only"* - why do you think so?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an X-Y question.

Answer (score 0):

why do you think so? Have you tried adding fonts in css because the default font may not support your language.